# how to implement code for display the text line by line by using animations?

Tags: android, animation

How to implement a **code** and **xml** by using animations to displaying the text line by line it means in the first line **" well come to world page"** in the second line **"how are you friend"** and in the third line **"Have a nice day"**.

Comment: <TextView android:singleLinetext=false />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will help you
 In your xml file write this property